# Mapping in elasticsearch for multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-emr

I want to apply following template to all the fields.
Currently I am applying this mapping only for "name" field.

Lets say I have some more fields also exa : "resedential_address","work_address","birth_place","DOB" etc.

How can I do this in efficient way. I know I can repeat the same block for all the fields.
Or is there a way where in I can apply following template to all the "text" fields ?

```
{
      "template": "*",
      "settings": {
      "analysis": {
      "filter": {
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 25
                }
            },
         "analyzer": {
            "case_insensitive": {
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "ngram_filter","lowercase"
               ]    
            },
            "search_analyzer":{
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": "lowercase"
                }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "case_insensitive",
               "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map all `text` fields with provided custom mapping then use `dynamic templates` feature as shown below:

```
{
      "template": "*",
      "settings": {
      "analysis": {
      "filter": {
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 25
                }
            },
         "analyzer": {
            "case_insensitive": {
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "ngram_filter","lowercase"
               ]    
            },
            "search_analyzer":{
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": "lowercase"
                }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
         "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "case_insensitive",
               "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
      }
   }
}
```

Above template will create the same custom mapping for all string fields like `name, residential_address, work_address ...`

Comment: Thanks @avr for very quick response !